# Zip all subdirectories in a directory and ignore files

Tags: bash, 7zip

Im looking for a script that can zip all subdirectories of a directory, but ignore the files within said directory.

e.g.

```
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/baz
/foo/barbaz.txt
```

Would become

```
/foo
/foo/bar.7z
/foo/baz.7z
/foo/barbas.txt
```

I've gotten as far as this but it zips every file as well which is totally unnecessary when most of the files in the parent directory are lightweight text or pdf files.

```
`for i in /foo/*; do f=$(basename -- "$i"); 7z a "/foo/$f.7z" "$i"; rm -Rf "$i"; done`
```

Comment: `for d in /foo/*/; do 7z a -sdel "${d%/}" "$d"; done` or to allow unpacking with correct relative paths `( cd /foo && for d in */; do 7z a -sdel "${d%/}" "$d"; done )` ?

Comment: @jhnc probably the latter.